# converting html to haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, haml

There is a projects.html file above.This file works successfully but when I convert this html file to haml file with http://html2haml.heroku.com/ , haml file doesn't work.

Can you see any difference between two files?

**projects.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sectoral Statistics'
            },
            tooltip: {
              pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}% - {point.y} proje</b> ',
              percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' % - '+ this.y +' proje';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    <% @results.each do |key,value| %>     
                      ['<%= key %>',<%= value %>,<%= value %>],
                    <% end %> 
                  ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

**projects.html.haml**

```
%script{:src => "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
%script{:src => "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"}
%script{:src => "http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"}
:javascript
  $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sectoral Statistics'
            },
            tooltip: {
              pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.percentage}% - {point.y} proje ',
              percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.point.name +': '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' % - '+ this.y +' proje';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                     @results.each do |key,value|      
                      [' key ', value , value ],
                  ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: It seems to me more like Javascript with HTML tags on top . Are you going to use it in a Rails project?

Comment: Yes,it's actually about javascript with html but I'm gonna use it in rails project

Comment: I would suggest to move your js from the views templates into separated files and include those files in the manifest file `application.js` . HTML2HAML cannot convert correctly in your case.You can search for `asset-pipeline` [in this RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and you'll get the idea for Rails way to organize your `js` and `css` .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in `html2haml`.

In your HTML, your last `script` tag looks something like this (I’ve cut it down for brevity):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  ...
});
</script>
```

The first line is indented, but the last isn’t. `html2haml` is only looking at the first line when determining how to indent the javascript, and this is resulting in Haml that looks like:

```
:javascript
  $(function () {
  ...
});
```

The last line – `});` – isn’t indented.

To work around it you should fix the indentation, in either your HTML or in the generated Haml.

Note that there is [another bug](https://github.com/haml/html2haml/issues/9) with `:javascript` filters you should be aware of. It think in this case you should be all right with that one.